# How to add footer view to a List in SwiftUI?

Tags: swiftui, swiftui-list

I'm trying to add a view to the bottom of a `List` while remaining in the safe zone. This is what I want to end up with, I'm referring to the "Updated: 5:26 AM":

[image]

What I tried is using the `Section` footer with a spacer, but that didn't work:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var selectedTab = 0

    var body: some View {
        TabView(selection: $selectedTab) {
            List {
                Section {
                    Text("Item 1")
                    Text("Item 1")
                    Text("Item 1")
                }
                Section(
                    footer: VStack {
                        Spacer()
                        Text("Updated at: 5:26 AM")
                            .frame(maxWidth: .infinity)
                    }
                ) {
                    Text("Item 1")
                    Text("Item 1")
                    Text("Item 1")
                }
            }
            .listStyle(InsetGroupedListStyle())
            .tabItem {
                Label("First", systemImage: "alarm")
            }
            Text("Content 2")
                .tabItem {
                    Label("Second", systemImage: "calendar")
                }
        }
    }
}
```

[image]

Then I tried a `VStack` as a section of of its own with a `Spacer` but no luck either:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var selectedTab = 0

    var body: some View {
        TabView(selection: $selectedTab) {
            List {
                Section {
                    Text("Item 1")
                    Text("Item 1")
                    Text("Item 1")
                }
                Section {
                    Text("Item 1")
                    Text("Item 1")
                    Text("Item 1")
                }
                VStack {
                    Spacer()
                    Text("Updated at: 5:26 AM")
                        .font(.footnote)
                        .foregroundColor(.secondary)
                        .frame(maxWidth: .infinity)
                }
                .listRowBackground(Color(.systemGroupedBackground))
            }
            .listStyle(InsetGroupedListStyle())
            .tabItem {
                Label("First", systemImage: "alarm")
            }
            Text("Content 2")
                .tabItem {
                    Label("Second", systemImage: "calendar")
                }
        }
    }
}
```

[image]

How do I achieve this while also considering the `List` might scroll? I'm trying to tack it on the end of the list, not floating.

Comment: It is not clear how it should look if there would be several such items sections and "Updated" goes out of visible area, then we scroll to bottom and ...?

Comment: scrolling to the bottom it would be above the tab bars. in auto layout, would pin to the bottom safe area with a high priority and pin below the last section with a lower priority I believe

Comment: I'm beginning to think this can't be done in SwiftUI. maybe I should set it as a sticky footer unless the list is bigger than the screen height. sounding messy

Answer (score 0):

You can put both `List` and `Text` together in `VStack` with no spacing:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var selectedTab = 0

    var body: some View {
        TabView(selection: $selectedTab) {
            VStack(spacing: 0) {
                List {
                    Section {
                        Text("Item 1")
                        Text("Item 1")
                        Text("Item 1")
                    }
                    Section {
                        Text("Item 1")
                        Text("Item 1")
                        Text("Item 1")
                    }
                }
                .listStyle(InsetGroupedListStyle())
                Text("Updated at: 5:26 AM")
                    .font(.footnote)
                    .foregroundColor(.secondary)
                    .frame(maxWidth: .infinity)
                    .background(Color(.systemGroupedBackground))
            }
            .tabItem {
                Label("First", systemImage: "alarm")
            }
            Text("Content 2")
                .tabItem {
                    Label("Second", systemImage: "calendar")
                }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I tried this but the `Text` view floats and the `List` scroll is only part of the screen

Comment: btw if I wanted to float, `.overlay` works better for this. But I'm trying to make this view at the bottom of the `List` view no matter how short or long it is (but not float it while scrolling)

Comment: @TruMan1 I understand now what you need. But what should happen if you scroll the list? Should the footer slide down and hide?

Comment: if the list is too long, the "Updated at" would be off the screen and at the bottom. The user won't see it until they finish scrolling to the bottom

Comment: now that I think about it, if the list is too long, it would behave just like adding a `Section` footer to the last section. But if its too short, that's when there'd be a spacer in between

Comment: @TruMan1 And what should happen to the footer when the list is short and the user starts scrolling?

Comment: But if it’s too short, there isn’t any scrolling available (like my screenshot). But if a large data set comes back, the list will provide the scroll

Comment: @TruMan1 You can always move/scroll/drag the list, even if it's short. So if the footer is *inside* the list - what should be its behaviour?

Comment: hmm I see, you're right. it feels like making it work within the last Section footer would be perfect. Even as a separate view in the list, but the spacer isn't working as expected in those scenarios